# How to tableview to a table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I am developing an iPad application. And one of the view in the app, in have a table view and I'm loading a table cell to the table view.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"tmpCell";
    AgendaListCellView *cell = (AgendaListCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AgendaListCellView_iPad" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = tmpCell;
    }
    cell.artist = [_mArAgendaList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell.
    [cell setRow:[_mArDictionaryObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

But now I need to add a table view inside the `AgendaListCellView` 
Is it possible to add a table to a cell?

See the 
image below

Im loading this one using a cell. Do u see 2 Text fields on right corner. This will load on randomly. And be reduced . Is thr any solution to do it ??
[image]

Comment: You want to add new UITableView in every cell? Well, it's probably possible but it will probably end up as a big mess. I don't think you understand how to use tables.

Comment: can u show us wat u r trying to implement through some images... we can provide a better solution to implement it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can add tableview inside cell. I would suggest you to create separate delegate class to handle delegate & datasource methods of tableview(inside cells) if all tables in cells have similar data source. It will minimize your code complexity.